# Error with Java's charAt()

Tags: java, char

I'm trying to create a program where the user enters a string, and the program echos it to the monitor with one character per line.

However, I can't compile what I've written. An error pops up at this line:

```
char c = word.charAt(i);
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class charAt

{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
   System.out.println("Give me a word, just one word:");
   Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
   String word = kb.nextLine();

   for(int i=0; i<word.length(); i++)
   char c = word.charAt(i);
   System.out.println(" " + c);
  }
}
```

Also, if you could explain your answer, that'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're missing brackets for your `for` loop. Could be part of the problem.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: And this is why some languages mandate braces after if/while/for...

Answer (score 3):

Without the brackets, Java will assume you meant this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
{
    char c = word.charAt(i);
}
System.out.println(" " + c);
```

The problem is that here `c` is outside the scope of the print statement. Therefore the compiler won't know what `c` refers to and will throw the error you are seeing. As @CupawnTae has noted, there's also the issue that a single variable declaration and no statements isn't even enough for a `for` loop.

Instead you should actually put the brackets in yourself like this, to remove the ambiguity and fix the scope:

```
for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
{
    char c = word.charAt(i);
    System.out.println(" " + c);
}
```

And the problem should go away. In general I strongly recommend always using brackets as it's easy to make simple mistakes like this without them.

Comment: almost right - see my answer - won't compile even if you remove the `println`

Comment: @CupawnTae Given the context I don't think OP has any intention of removing the `println` statement. Good point though.

Comment: well as the OP says in the question, the error appears on the `char c` line, not the `println`, so maybe I'm being pedantic, but the actual error he's seeing is not caused by an out-of-scope variable, it's caused by an invalid loop.

Comment: also, your initial statement is wrong - the compiler *doesn't* treat it the same as the block version

Comment: @CupawnTae Could you elaborate on that last comment?

Comment: well, try it without the braces and without the println - it gives a compile error on the `char c` - as I explained in my answer

Comment: @CupawnTae No I mean yes that will cause an error, but how does that make my initial statement incorrect? It's a broken for loop sure, but that's still how the compiler would treat it, correct?

Comment: No. The code that you say is equivalent will compile (being a valid block), whereas the original code will not compile because it's not a valid statement. Therefore they can't be equivalent. I.e. java will *not* assume you meant that.

Comment: Just saw your edit and I see where the confusion is coming from. It's not that `char c...` isn't **enough** for the loop, it's that it's not **valid** there. You can have a loop with no statements, e.g. `for(;;);` will loop infinitely, doing nothing but generating heat. But `for (;;) char c;` is not the same as `for (;;) {char c;}` - the first won't compile and the second will.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop is more properly indented as,

```
for(int i=0; i<word.length(); i++)
  char c = word.charAt(i); // <-- Also, not a valid location to declare the char
                           // as noted by cupawntae
System.out.println(" " + c);
```

The above won't compile because `c` isn't visible at the `println` statement. Also, it's not a valid location to declare `char c` but even if it were - it wouldn't be accessable as a naked statement. So, you could add braces to wrap the `println()` into the same block -

```
for(int i=0; i<word.length(); i++) {
  char c = word.charAt(i);
  System.out.println(" " + c);
}
```

or you could use

```
for(int i=0; i<word.length(); i++)
  System.out.println(" " + word.charAt(i));
```

or use [`String.toCharArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) like,

```
for (char c : word.toCharArray())
  System.out.println(" " + c);
```

Comment: almost right - see my answer - won't compile even if you remove the `println`

Comment: @CupawnTae My code will compile. You are also correct that it's not a valid statement location without a new block.

Comment: I meant the original code won't compile without the println and therefore the println isn't the problem. Of course it would be a problem if there were a valid block and it wasn't in it, but it doesn't get to be a problem because there isn't a valid variable declaration anywhere for it to not be in scope of :)

Answer (score 2):

As other answers have pointed out, your loop won't work as-is because the `println` won't be able to see the `char c` variable.

However, **this is not the reason for the error you are seeing.** In fact, your compiler probably won't even complain about that line because it doesn't get far enough to determine that you have a scope problem.

To demonstrate, if you remove the `System.out.println` it *still* won't compile. The reason is that it's not valid to declare a variable like this:

```
for (;;) char c='a';
```

You'll get an error stating that `char c='a';` is not a statement.

You can use `for` (and other loops, conditionals etc.) with either

1. a single statement like `System.out.println(...);` *or*
2. a block enclosed in braces `{...}`

A variable declaration is not a simple statement, and therefore if you want to declare a variable, you must enclose it in a block with braces `{...}`

Once you do this, it will be obvious that the `println` needs to be inside this block. So you will end with the same code as the other answers, and the bottom line is that your problem is missing braces.

Comment: While it's true it won't compile, even if it would - it wouldn't do any work. So clearly it's not supposed to be a naked variable declaration. But still, +1 for being *technically* correct about valid statements.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch agreed. The main thing is that no-one had addressed the actual error the that OP reported, which was nothing to do with the `println`

Answer (score 1):

Just put `System.out.println(c)` in the scope of for loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class charAt

{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Give me a word, just one word:");
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        String word = kb.nextLine();

        for(int i=0; i<word.length(); i++)
        {
            char c = word.charAt(i);
            System.out.println(" " + c);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just missed the brackets! Your **char c** is out of scope. Following will work.

```
for(int i=0; i<word.length(); i++) {
   char c = word.charAt(i);
   System.out.println(" " + c);
}
```

You can alternatively do

```
for(int i=0; i<word.length(); i++)
System.out.println(" " + word.charAt(i));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as others have indicated, is this part by itself:

```
for(int i=0; i<word.length(); i++)
    char c = word.charAt(i);
```

The second line is a "Local Variable Declaration Statement". The *[specification of the Java Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4)* states that:

> Every local variable declaration statement is *immediately* contained by
>   a block.

A *block* is "a sequence of statements, local class declarations, and local variable declaration statements ***within braces***" (JLS).

Your line `char c = ...` is not *immediately* contained inside a block (because it is a statement attached to a `for` loop).

The Java language does not recognize it as a variable declaration at all - so the errors you get are confusing (I'm seeing 6 different errors in Eclipse). 
The compiler not saying "Local Variable Declaration statement not contained in a block" because at a very low level of the grammar, it doesn't even take the possibility into account that this could be a variable declaration statement.

The solution is simple though; at any place in Java where you can have a "statement" you can also have a block (which Java then sees as a *block statement*). Remember that a block is a number of statements enclosed *within braces*. So - place braces around your variable declaration statement and it will compile.

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    char c = word.charAt(i);
}
```

The next step is, of course, to move your `System.out.println` statement inside this block, since local variables are only visible within the block in which they are declared.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class charAt

{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
   System.out.println("Give me a word, just one word:");
   Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
   String word = kb.nextLine();

   char[] charArray = word.toCharArray();

   for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length(); i++) {
       System.out.println("char[" + i + "]: " + new String(charArray[i]");
   }
}
```

**DISCLAIMER:** Haven't actually tested this